# Calculate categorical variable from dates in Excel

Tags: excel, datetime, date-range

I'm working on a project that is trying to compare relationships between variables before / during / after Covid shutdown in my area. I'm trying to create a categorical variable (i.e., before, during, after) using the dates in Excel

I looked up a tutorial site, and it seems like this should work. It should see if the date is before the beginning of the Covid shutdown and if so, assign 0 for baseline; then see if it's after the shutdown ended and assign 2; and otherwise assign 1 because it was during the shutdown.

`=IF(COUNTIF(B2,"<= 2020-03-12"),0,IF(COUNTIF(B2,">2020-5-10"),2,1))`

It's just assigning 1 for everything. I have the reference cell formatted as a datetime variable with the same format "yyyy-mm-dd" and that seems like it is exactly what the tutorials said.

Any advice about what went wrong? I'd rather not go through the process of trying to switch to R if I can avoid it.

Comment: Why are you using countif?  Just lose the two `countif`s and you should  be OK.

Comment: Another way to go on these kinds of mappings is to use a range lookup like is built into VLookup().  `=VLookup(B2,{2020-03-12,0; 2020-05-10,1; 2999-12-31,2},2)`. For me this is slightly easier to read, rather than trying to parse your way through a thicket of `IF()` functions, where you have to remember to get the right number of close-parens.

Comment: [Dates above in double-quotes].

Answer (score 0):

You're making this harder than necessary.

Define start and end dates. Here they're in `$G$2:$G$3`. You could hard code them directly in the formula if you want.

In cell `C3`, and copied down the column:

```
=IF(B2 <= $G$2, 0, IF(B2 > $G$3, 2, 1))
```

I find this cleaner and easier to read than the VLookup() @Chris Mauer provided, but that's just a matter of taste.

|  | **A** | **B** | **C** | **D** | **E** | **F** | **G** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** |  | Dates | COVID |  |  | Target | Dates |
| **2** |  | 3/12/20 | 0 |  |  | Pre | 3/12/20 |
| **3** |  | 3/13/20 | 1 |  |  | Post | 5/10/20 |
| **4** |  | 5/10/20 | 1 |  |  |  |  |
| **5** |  | 5/11/20 | 2 |  |  |  |  |

Comment: I don't have enough stack overflow cred to be able to upvote an answer, but I would upvote if I could. Thanks!